# Why does my code break at the first if statement?

Tags: c++, c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *names;
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char name[100];

    printf ("Enter number 4 is you want to stop inputting names.\n");

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("Input:\n");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name),stdin);
        printf ("%s", name);

        if (strcmp(name, "end")!= 0)
        {
            printf ("hello");
        }

        if (strcmp (name, "end")== 0)
        {
            printf("bye ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to keep looping to get the user input and break out of the loop when the user enter a certain character or word. 
But when I input "end" I expected the output to be "bye" but the output is "hello".

Comment: Looks like a `}` is missing... And why are you displaying `printf ("Enter number 4 is you want to stop inputting names.\n");`?

Comment: sry thats a typo error, i was trying to use isalpha() before that and forgot to change it but it still doesnt work

Comment: hard to read. use correct identation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unless you intent to mix the two languages, please decide if you want to ask about C or C++ and only use the related tag.

Comment: BTW, you should remove the C++ language tag, or use the C++ header files.  The C and C++ are different languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` type for text and C doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is subtle. Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for `fgets`. Then look at the value of `name` in the debugger after the call to `fgets`.

`fgets` ends the input when it sees a newline character, **but** it includes the newline character in the result. So `name` ends up with the character string `"end\n"`; comparing that to `"end"` will fail.

If you're going to use `fgets` you have to allow for that newline character, and compare with `"end\n"`.

If this is C code, use `scanf`. If this is C++ code, use `std::cin` with a stream extractor.

Comment: Just to be sure: is the 'newline' character always \n on all OSes? Or could it be \r (or even \r\n)?

Comment: @Adrian -- in C and C++ code the character `'\n'` is a newline. On output the standard library is responsible for translating that character into whatever sequence of bytes is needed to start a new line on the target platform, and vice versa on input.

Answer (score 0):

That's caused by your input function `fgets`. Use `cin` instead and you will get your expected output "**bye**" once you input "**end**".

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std; 

  int main (void) {

    char *names;
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char name[100];

    printf ("Enter number 4 is you want to stop inputting names.\n");

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("Input:\n");
        cin >> name;
        printf ("%s", name);

     if (strcmp(name, "end")!= 0)
     {
         printf ("hello");
     }

     else if (strcmp (name, "end")== 0)
     {
         printf("bye ");
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, the problem goes away. That's not the same as "the error is fixed". A good answer would explain where this problem comes from and why the "fix" works. And since it's not at all clear that this code is being compiled as C++ (the **only** C++ feature used here is the omitted return value from `main`), a C++ solution may not be appropriate. I've removed my previous comment, which was overly harsh.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strcmp` use `strncmp`. `strcmp` will compare all characters in your strings until a terminating null-character is reached or characters differ. `strncmp` will only compare the first n values in both strings. Also you should add `break` after `printf("bye")` to leave the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (void)
{
    char *names;
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char name[100];

    printf ("Enter number 4 is you want to stop inputting names.\n");

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("Input:\n");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name),stdin);
        printf ("%s", name);

        if (strncmp(name, "end", 3)!= 0)
        {
            printf ("hello");
        }

        if (strncmp (name, "end", 3)== 0)
        {
            printf("bye ");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I recently started on c and I have been stuck at this for quite sometime.

Comment: This is wrong. `strcmp(name, "end")` will not look beyond the 4th character in `name` because `"end"` has only 4 characters.

Comment: Changing to `strncmp` makes this particular example "work", because `fgets` reads up to a newline and puts the newline character into `name`. But that has nothing to do with `name` being an array of 100 characters. The value in `name` is a nul-terminated character string (i.e., a C-style string), and `strcmp` knows how to handle that. You really don't want to be hardcoding the length of the text that you're comparing to for every string comparison. That's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right, I got that wrong. Never had to compare a whole text.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mention: `fgets()` stores the end-of-line character `\n`, too. If you compare with `"end\n"` it will work.